# What is the bottle that Lister uses as a carafe at dinner?

Tags: red-dwarf

In the episode Polymorph, as Lister is serving dinner with all re-purposed medical equipment, he pulls out some red wine in a clear glass vessel that was sitting on its side. The audience members are all grossed out, so I'm wondering if it has a specific purpose I'm missing, probably medical/body fluid related?

[image]

Comment: do you have a screenshot?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's hard to tell, unless you are familiar with older hospital equipment, but it's an older style hospital urinal.  It's not on screen much, but here's a grab where you can see the rough shape:
[image: Lister Holding the Glass Urinal]

And, here, you can note how it rests on the table, without spilling it's contents
[image: Urinal resting on the table]

A quick image google will show you a number of styles, but it's basically like this one:
[image: Glass Urinal from images.google.com]

Comment: I've been in hospital and had to use a cardboard container, much the same shape, if somewhat more angular.

Comment: @AJFaraday -- Yep; they are usually plastic, these days, but the old glass ones were a staple of the world wars.

Comment: @AJFaraday most of those style of things (urinals, kidney dishes etc) are being moved over to single use cardboard substitutes in the NHS for reasons of "infection control".

Comment: @Moo It's almost as though there are sick people in hospitals.

Comment: @AJFaraday Its almost as if current day healthcare professionals dont want to spend time cleaning something that could more easily be disposable.  There wqs nothing wrong with the stainless steel medical grade stuff that used to be used, it just had to be cleaned properly after use - we would much rather line the pockets of a medical equipment supply company these days than get someone to pop stuff in a steam pressure sluice...

Comment: @moo that's a fair point, although it's also more cost effective. The staff time is worth more than extra moulded cardboard bottles. Of course, that's the way it should be. People and their expertise is valuable, and if more of that time can be spent on the patients, so much the better... That was a funny scene of Red Dwarf, huh?

Answer (score 7):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on the above answer, but wished to provide a more accurate response.

This is a glass urine bottle for use by bed-bound patients.

For guys of a certain age, this brings back memories of embarrassment, the thought of spillages in bed, and of it being thrust upon you by stern looking matrons.

Comment: “it being thrust upon you by stern looking matrons” — so turned on right now.